# How to accept null JTextField in java?

Tags: java, mysql, swing

Actually I am working on Java Swing for front end and Mysql as a back end for my system.
I have one Java swing form which contains some JTextField so in that some JTextField required to fill compulsory and some are optional. But when I have not entered any values in that optional JTextField it shows NumberFormatException.
I have set null in my mysql database table to those optional fields but still its not working.

Can you please help me with this?

Thank you

```
        String value1=(String)cb.getSelectedItem();
        String value2=t2.getText();
        String value3=t3.getText();
        String value4=t4.getText();
        String value5=(String)cb5.getSelectedItem();        
        double value6=Double.parseDouble(t6.getText());
        String value7=(String)cb7.getSelectedItem();
        double value8=Double.parseDouble(t8.getText());
        String value9=t9.getText();

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/Priyanka","root","root");
                ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into ReceiptsVoucher values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);");

                ps.setString(1,value1);
                ps.setString(2,value2);
                ps.setString(3,value3);
                ps.setString(4,value4);
                ps.setString(5,value5);
                ps.setDouble(6,value6);
                ps.setString(7,value7);
                ps.setDouble(8,value8);
                ps.setString(9,value9);  

        int r=ps.executeUpdate();
        if(r==0)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Record not Inserted retry"," ",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Record Inserted Sucessfully"," ",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        ps.close();
        con.close();
```

JComboxBox ie cb7 and JTextField t8 are optional fields

```
        String value1=(String)cb.getSelectedItem();
        String value2=t2.getText();
        String value3=t3.getText();
        String value4=t4.getText();
        String value5=(String)cb5.getSelectedItem();        
        double value6=Double.parseDouble(t6.getText());
        String value7=(String)cb7.getSelectedItem(); 
        String v8=t8.getText();
        //double value8=Double.parseDouble(t8.getText());                   
        String value9=t9.getText();

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/Priyanka","root","root");
                ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into ReceiptsVoucher values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);");

                ps.setString(1,value1);
                ps.setString(2,value2);
                ps.setString(3,value3);
                ps.setString(4,value4);
                ps.setString(5,value5);
                ps.setDouble(6,value6);
                ps.setString(7,value7);
                if(v8 != null && !v8.isEmpty()) 
                {
                    double value8=Double.parseDouble(v8);
                    ps.setDouble(8, value8);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    ps.setNull(8, Types.DOUBLE);
                }
                //ps.setDouble(8,value8);
                ps.setString(9,value9);  

        int r=ps.executeUpdate();
        if(r==0)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Record not Inserted retry"," ",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Record Inserted Sucessfully"," ",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        ps.close();
        con.close();
```

Problem solved. This worksfine now. Thank you all

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Can you provide the sample code ?

Comment: Are you sure you are not trying to parse the JTextField content to number?

Comment: Omar I am parsing JTextField content to double

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are converting the textfield value to some number like

```
Double.parseDouble(t8.getText());
```

this will throw **NumberFormatException**.

You should check null value possibility of textfield t8 in your case and if you should set 
db NULL value in database in java. Do something like this.

```
try {

value8 = Double.parseDouble(t8.getText());

} catch (NumberFormatException) {

value8 = 0.0;

}

String query = "INSERT INTO your_table(val) VALUES (?)";
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(query);
if ( value8 != null && !value8.isEmpty()) {
   st.setDouble(1, value8);
} else {
   st.setNull(1, Types.DOUBLE);
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is Types.DOUBLE ?

Comment: see this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html

Comment: if ( value8 != null && !value8.isEmpty()) getting error on this lineis The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) 
  double, null
 - Cannot invoke isEmpty() on the primitive type double

Comment: @PriyankaPawar - use wrapper class. replace double to Double

Comment: @PriyankaPawar - replace double value8=Double.parseDouble(t8.getText()); to Double value8=Double.parseDouble(t8.getText());

Comment: Sorry but I am too much confuse cause you are taking value8 as double and intializing to value8="" so its shows error

Answer (score 1):

You may use a default value for null entry. Then send it to database.

Like:

```
if(st == null)
  st = "";
```

When you are working with it check for the same again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but Value should be numeric so i guess it will not work

Comment: Sorry I did not see the codes here before...

Answer (score 0):

here is your problem

```
 double value8=Double.parseDouble(t8.getText());
```

check for null or empty string before parsing

Comment: Yes I got it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
double value8=Double.parseDouble(t8.getText());
```

When you entered nothing to `JtextFielad` t8, Your code trying to convert `null` value to double, that causes `NumberFormat Exception`

Use the following snippet may solve your problem

```
String value8=t8.getText();
```

And

```
ps.setString(8,value8);
```

Treat the value8 as `String`

You can use a method for type checking

```
 public static boolean isNumeric(String str)  
 {  
 try  
  {  
   double d = Double.parseDouble(str);  
   }  
  catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
  {  
   return false;  
  }  
  return true;  
 }

 }
```

Call the above method from where you want to check

Comment: you are skipping type checking (convert to double) in this case.

Comment: yes u are right my code is trying to convert null value to double but in same instance how can i take value8 as string and as double also

Answer (score -1):

I think, You are parsing `null`. and thats why you are gettting `NumberFormatException`. If you get null value from mysql side. Compare it put it as a empty string `""`. Then you will not get Exception.

Comment: you are skipping type checking (convert to double) in this case.

Comment: Yeah Man that you have to do it Further. I have told here that how to avoid NuberFormatException. Further things, the problem who have posted can done easily, isn't it?